# How to ssh into a VM within if else block using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

How to ssh into a VM within if else block using shell script?

```
docker build -t qtech/security-categories-microservice:latest .
docker run -d --name sec-cat-ms qtech/security-categories-microservice:latest
sleep 10
status=$(docker ps | grep sec-cat-ms | awk '{print $1}')
echo "$status"
if   [ "$status" != "" ]; then
        docker push qtech/security-categories-microservice:latest      

        ssh -i ip.pem -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -tt root@xx.xx.xx.xx <<-'EOF'
        ./refresh.sh
        sleep 10
        docker service ls
        docker ps
        exit
        EOF

        pwd
        docker rm -f sec-cat-ms
        docker rmi -f $(docker images qtech/security-categories-microservice -q)
        sleep 5
         
elif [ "$status" = "" ]; then
        docker logs sec-cat-ms &> Security-Categories-MicroService-Error-Logs.txt &
        docker rm -f sec-cat-ms
        docker rmi -f $(docker images qtech/security-categories-microservice -q)
        exit 1
fi
```

While trying to execute this code bash throws below error message.

```
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

We did close if block with `fi` but it still throws above error message.

We are running this code from the jenkins shell job

So, How to ssh into a VM within if else block using shell script?

Comment: the ending `EOF` have to be at the beginning of a new line

Comment: Always first test your script to https://shellcheck.net before asking here. Thanks

Comment: Using `<<-` allows you to indent the here-document with tabs, but you appear to indented with spaces instead. Also, from the error message, you're running this script with dash instead of bash.

Comment: after using remote server commands between ```<EOF EOF``` now  jenkins is throwing this error message. ```/tmp/jenkins14485282915229511017.sh: 14: cannot open EOF: No such file```

Answer (score 0):

Shellcheck.net - use it over and over, every time your script misbehaves.

Some simple examples templates -

```
#!/bin/bash

if true
then echo simple quotes
     ssh localhost '
         date
         sleep 2
         date
     '
fi

if true
then echo SIMPLE here-doc with creative spacing
     ssh localhost <<_____EOT
         date; sleep 2
         date
_____EOT
fi

if true
then echo here-string
     ssh localhost <<< 'date; sleep 2; date'
fi

if true
then echo piped input
     echo '
         date
         sleep 2
         date
     ' | ssh localhost
fi
```

Quotes may matter a lot, depending on what's embedded (and how) in your lists of commands.

Comment: Don't have `dash` handy, ymmv.